# How can I better check for a pair using a data set of card numbers and their suits?

Tags: python, if-statement, time-complexity, simplify

I have recently taken it upon my self to create a program that plays DJ Wild the poker game. I haven't ran into many bumps but I am not very familiar with time complexity which I know that many programs can run into. This is making me cautious about how many and how long my if statements are. Thus a question occurred, can I simplify the following if statement that uses the `count` method.

`

```
#imports

import random
import itertools


#declaration of the variables
ante = 0
bonus = 0
balance = 200
cards = []
hands0 = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
hands1 = ["Spade", "Club", "Diamond", "Heart"]

#initializing the card deck
carddeck = list(itertools.product(['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K'],["Spade", "Club", "Diamond", "Heart"]))


#shuffling the deck
random.shuffle(carddeck)


#drawing n number of cards from the shuffled deck
def user(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print("Player:", carddeck[i][0], carddeck[i][1])
        cards.append(carddeck[i][0])
        cards.append(carddeck[i][1])
        carddeck.remove(carddeck[i])
        

user(5)
#print(cards)
if cards.count('2') == 2 or \
   cards.count('3') == 2 or \
   cards.count('4') == 2 or \
   cards.count('5') == 2 or \
   cards.count('6') == 2 or \
   cards.count('7') == 2 or \
   cards.count('8') == 2 or \
   cards.count('9') == 2 or \
   cards.count('10') == 2 or \
   cards.count('J') == 2 or \
   cards.count('Q') == 2 or \
   cards.count('K') == 2 or \
   cards.count('A') == 2:   
    print("You have a pair")
else:
    print("You don't have a pair")
```

`

I have tried using the line breaks with all the `\` implemented but I can't help but think that there is a more simplistic way to check for pairs using the list data for the cards created and dealt to the player.

Answer (score 0):

- initialize boolean to false
- loop the hands0 array
- check value of array
- if its true set your boolean to true and break your for loop
- then you can check against your boolean

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).